# What is the definition of Mitotic Index?

Tags: cancer

Sometimes I find Mitotic Index defined as (i) the number of dividing cells over the **number of non-dividing cells**, other times as the (ii) the number of dividing cells over the **total number of cells**...

When reading a paper, which definition is more likely to be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [cancer.gov](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms?cdrid=386225), it's the **ratio** of number of dividing cells to the number of cells not undergoing mitosis. This is equivalent to the number of dividing cells **over** the total number of cells.

Note that most papers, [such as this one](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1354/vp.44-3-335?url_ver=Z39.88-2003&rfr_id=ori%3Arid%3Acrossref.org&rfr_dat=cr_pub%3Dpubmed&), report the mitotic index as a value from 0-100 (I.E. a percentage)

Comment: I might be missing something... but is it not the total number of cells = dividing (undergoing mitosis) + non-dividing cells (not undergoing mitosis)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. A 1:1 ratio of dividing cells to non dividing cells would result in a mitotic index of 1/(1+1) = 50%.

Comment: The answer is slightly misleading, as "dividing cells" can refer to cells being in cell cycle (as opposed to G0 / senescent state), whereas the mitotic index refers to cells "undergoing division" (cancer.gov), which refers to cells where the material is currently being divided to two different daughter cells - which corresponds to the "mitosis" cell cycle phase of dividing cells.